# Best widget for a chat session in Qt

Tags: qt, xmpp, chat

I am implementing a Desktop Qt application which uses an XMPP library to chat. I am trying to find the best approach in terms of performance, easy to modify, add custom stuff (for instance, show a thumbnain if someone sends me an image)...
I would like to know which approach do you think is the best:
- Each element as a layout or widget and add them one by one (it seems to be slow)
- ListWidget items overloading paint event (problem: don't know item height before painting)
- Use a rich text widget and build the chat as a HTML page (didn't tried it yet)
- ??

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QListView would be good for simple IRC chat. If you are planning to implement some advanced text styling (different fonts, etc.) or images (like you said) WebView is the way to go. Additionally, much simpler way than QListView.

There's even an example Qt Google Chat project which uses QtWebKit: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/webkit-googlechat.html

Comment: Hi user, thanks for your help. I need a cool widget since I would like to put some stuff like, for instance, WhatsApp (images, sounds, group chat...)

Comment: @DídacPérez: group chat is a different layer, but sounds should be quite easy with webview. You have HTML5 audio and video built in.

Comment: @DídacPérez Did you make progress with QWebView? I was thinking to take the same path and i need some wizdom :).

Comment: No success, I have not been working on it since a couple of months ago. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for QListView with model attached and custom delegates etc..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The point is that I don't previously know the lenght of the texto, so maybe I would have to stretch the height of the item, and I am not able to do this since I paint everything in the paint() method.

Comment: I can use QFontMetrics to compute the height of the text but it takes too much time to compute the metrics of all the items... :-(

Comment: One thing to consider in this solution is if its possible to select text across multiple list items?